# Excel vba auto run macro on workbook open

Tags: excel, autorun, vba

I have a `Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` which i want to automatically run for all users. The problems is these users barely know or bother to enable macro when entering data. Is there a way to force macro to automatically run on this workbook? I have seen an article about an event called `Workbook_Open ()` but i have no idea on how to use it. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, you can't force a workbook to enable macros without explicit input from the user.

What you can do though, is set all the sheets the user would need to hidden. Then create a visible sheet with just a textbox or something that says "Please enable macros to continue." Then use the `Workbook_Open` event to hide that sheet and unhide the other sheets.

Additionally, use the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event to re-hide the sheets when the user saves the spreadsheet, so the check has to be performed every time.

Additional tip: When hiding sheets using VBA, try to use `xlSheetVeryHidden` versus `xlSheetHidden`. This means the users won't be able to unhide them from excel like a normal hidden sheet (so you can avoid a stubborn user using that loophole).

EDIT: Here's some sample code, with made-up sheet names of course:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

Worksheets("Data1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Worksheets("Data2").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Worksheets("Welcome").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Worksheets("Welcome").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Worksheets("Data1").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Worksheets("Data2").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Worksheets("Data1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Worksheets("Data2").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Worksheets("Welcome").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End Sub
```